# Text is english, citation style is in another language

Tags: bibtex, languages

My LaTeX document is English but when I cite multiple authors

> Teyseyre **und** Campo

occurs instead of

> Teyseyre **and** Campo

I set `\selectlanguage{english}` and for every single entry I added `language = {english}`.

I also tried adding the following which I found in another thread:

```
\usepackage{babelbib} 
\selectbiblanguage{english}

\renewcommand\betweenauthors{and}
\providecommand\harvardand{}
\renewcommand\harvardand{and}
```

Tt still displays the German "und". 
Can someone help me getting rid of it?

Comment: Do you use BibLaTeX? If you do, `\usepackage[english]{babel}` fixes your issue.

Comment: I do use \usepackage[english]{babel} and natbib

Comment: Which bibliography style do you use?

Comment: I'm using natbib

Comment: `natbib` is not a 'style': what argument are you giving `\bibliographystyle`?

Comment: You should consider change from natbib to biblatex. Biblatex has a better language support and is more flexible. To achieve what you want with biblatex you need only the babel line, the .bib call `\bibliography{file.bib}` and `\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}` (or whatever style you want.

Comment: @jon I use natdin then

Comment: @ppr when changin \usepackage{natbib} to your expression my document suddenly contains 12 errors. what bibliographystyle do I need?

Comment: @keinabel Switching to `biblatex` is (unfortunately) not as simple as changing one line in the preamble. You might want to read [What to do to switch to `biblatex`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864), [`biblatex` for idiots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864) and [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864). `natdin.bst` is a German citation style and thus uses German localisation, some words can be changed though. Is it only the "and" you are interested in, or is there more?

Comment: @moewe switching to bibliographystyle plainnat did the job

Comment: @moewe Sorry but I don't see the difficulty to switch to `biblatex`. You just have to install `biblatex` package and put two lines in your preamble... Of course you should be aware that `\citep{}` becomes `\autocite{}` (probably the reason why @keinabel has 12 errors).

Answer (score 9):

The bibliography style `natdin` lets users cite and reference pieces according to the German standard "DIN 1505, Parts 2 and 3" (citing from the header of `natdin.bst`). As such, it shouldn't come as a surprise that you get the German connector particle "und" rather than, say, "and". Changing parameters such as `\harvardand` will have no effect whatsoever since the `natdin` bibliography style doesn't use that macro.

Assuming you want to stick with `natdin` as your bibliography style and all you want to do is change the connector particle from "und" to "and", you could proceed as follows:

- Find the file `natdin.bst` on your computer and make a copy, to be called, say, `mynatdin.bst`. (Never edit an original file that's part of the TeX distribution directly.)
- Open `mynatdin.bst` in your favorite text editor and search for the BibTeX function named `und`. (It's on line 181 in my copy of this file.) Given your description, this function is probably set up as

  ```
  FUNCTION { und } { " und " }
  ```

  Change it to

  ```
  FUNCTION { und } { " and " }
  ```
- Next, search for the function `ua.etal` (probably just a few lines up from the `und` function). Change it so that it says

  ```
  FUNCTION { ua.etal } { " et~al." }
  ```
- Save the file `mynatdin.bst`, either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by your TeX distribution. If you choose the latter option, you will probably also need to update/refresh the TeX filename database in an appropriate way.
- Start using the new bibliography style my issuing the command

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{mynatdin}
  ```

  in your main tex file. Be sure run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully update the work of BibTeX and LaTeX.

Answer (score 0):

Example: I want a quote in English, but it is appearing in Portuguese, as follows:

According to Enevoldsen and Xydis (2015) xxxxxxxx (the letter "e" appears in Portuguese)
According to Enevoldsen and Xydis (2015) xxxxxxxx (I want it)

########## Solution #############

Look for features with the extension ".bst", if you have more than one feature of this, you will have to change all of them. Now in this feature search for the function "FUNCTION {bbl.and}", then search for the letter of your language (in this case "e") and change to the desired language (in this case "and"). Don't forget to change all ".bst".

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Modifying the existing `bst` file is essentially the existing answer.  It does have the better advise to copy the file so that you're only editing a local version, and not the original file.