# Changing Citation Abbreviation Language

Tags: natbib, languages, naming

I want to change in-text citation abbreviation. I mean, I want to use Turkish version of English abbreviation. I searched before I asked queation but I can not figure out.

For example,

Davidson ve MacKinnon (1993) instead of Davidson and MacKinnon (1993)

or

Heckman ve diğ. (2010) instead of Heckman et al. (2010).

```
\documentclass[a4,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage [top=2 cm, bottom=2cm, right=3cm, left=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue, linkcolor=blue}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Turkish is not supported. So you must adopt a different solution. See the answer to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141506/text-is-english-citation-style-is-in-another-language), I just did it and it worked for me, as you can see [in this link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QB9fc.png).

Comment: Dear @Alenanno, thank you for your guideline. I read the answer. But I still can not the fix problem. I use natbib and I found my natbib abbrvnat.bst file. I changed all "and" and all "et al.", appropriately. Can you send me your solution more explicitly?

Comment: You shouldn't change your files because you might break something or create problems. Always modify a copy and rename it with a customized name, so that your TeX distribution doesn't get confused. Re-download your `abbrvnat.bst` file and paste it where you found the other one. Then, take the modified one and rename it like `turkabbrv.bst`. Now you should have two: the original and the new one. In your document simply call `\bibliographystyle{turkabbrv}` and that's it.