# changing citation from "u.a"., "und" to et.al., "and"

Tags: bibtex

I am using these packages:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}    
\usepackage[round, sort&compress]{natbib}   
\usepackage[ sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{dinat}
```

However I am writing in English, but the template is German. 
I changed all german language stuff to English.
And I know that dinat is a German citation thing.
I even tried to change the `dinat.bst` file, but failed and nothing happend.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text is english, citation style is in another language](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141506/text-is-english-citation-style-is-in-another-language)

Comment: @Sango - Not a duplicate: The current query employs the bib style `dinat`, whereas the one you've referenced uses the bib style `natdin`. This matters quite a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Starting on line 109 of `dinat.bst`, one finds the following lines of code:

```
FUNCTION {push.bd}        { "Bd." }
FUNCTION {push.diplom}    { "Diplomarbeit" }
FUNCTION {push.disser}    { "Dissertation" }
FUNCTION {push.forschung} { "Forschungsbericht" }
FUNCTION {push.hrsg}      { "Hrsg." }
FUNCTION {push.in}        { "In:" }
FUNCTION {push.isbn}      { "ISBN" }
FUNCTION {push.issn}      { "ISSN" }
FUNCTION {push.kap}       { "Kap." }
FUNCTION {push.nr}        { "Nr." }
FUNCTION {push.sn}        { "S" }
FUNCTION {push.s}         { "S." }
FUNCTION {push.siehe}     { "Siehe" }
FUNCTION {push.ua}        { "u.\,a." }
FUNCTION {push.und}       { "und" }
FUNCTION {push.url.name}  { "URL" }
FUNCTION {push.veranst}   { "Veranst." }
FUNCTION {push.von}       { "von" }
FUNCTION {push.zugriff}   { "Zugriffsdatum" }

FUNCTION {push.cite}      { "\citep" }
```

I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Make a copy of the file `dinat.bst` and name the copy, say, `dinat-en.bst`. Don't edit an original file of the TeX distribution directly.
- Open the file `dinat-en.bst` in a text editor -- the program you use to edit your tex files will do fine -- and proceed to line 109.
- Edit the 20 functions as needed. E.g., change the lines

  ```
  FUNCTION {push.ua}        { "u.\,a." }
  FUNCTION {push.und}       { "und" }
  ```

  to

  ```
  FUNCTION {push.ua}        { "et~al." }
  FUNCTION {push.und}       { "and" }
  ```
- Save the file `dinat-en.bst` either in the directory where your main tex file (the file with the instructions `\bibliographystyle` and `\bibliography`) is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to also update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably.
- In your main tex file, change

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{dinat}
  ```

  to

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{dinat-en}
  ```

  save the tex file, and perform a full recompile cycle -- LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more -- to fully propagate the changes.